# Google drive sdk downloadUrl returns 404

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm using the drive SDK for my download application, according to the documentation I must query the files metadata with files.get() which I do here:

```java
File remoteFile = this.driveClient.files().get(this.remoteMediaId).execute();
```

The response I'm given has all of the described metadata including a downloadUrl:

```js
{
  "alternateLink" : "https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9G3K3KUUcIISUdXMHkycUNFLVE/edit?usp=drive_web",
  "createdDate" : "2013-04-29T21:32:06.009Z",
  "downloadUrl" : "https://doc-04-9o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/kgbtvvv26q246qm8m1k4g2in1v7bhclv/e41n570nep6dionm41b8g25ennqqspmh/1367863200000/14985545053951403951/14985545053951403951/0B9G3K3KUUcIISUdXMHkycUNFLVE?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true",
...
```

I then make an http request for the file with the provided download link:

```java
HttpResponse downloadResponse = null;
    try {
        log.info(downloadUrl);
        log.info(downloadUrl.equals(remoteFile.getDownloadUrl()));
        downloadResponse = this.driveClient.getRequestFactory()
                .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(downloadUrl))
                .execute();
...
```

The response for the majority of the files is a 404, however some work.  If I just run a curl request per the documentation I also get a 404.

```bsh
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer ya29.***********...' 'https://doc-04-9o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/kgbtvvv26q246qm8m1k4g2in1v7bhclv/e41n570nep6dionm41b8g25ennqqspmh/1367863200000/14985545053951403951/14985545053951403951/0B9G3K3KUUcIISUdXMHkycUNFLVE?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true'
* About to connect() to doc-04-9o-docs.googleusercontent.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.239.140...
* connected
* Connected to doc-04-9o-docs.googleusercontent.com (74.125.239.140) port 443 (#0)
...
> GET /docs/securesc/kgbtvvv26q246qm8m1k4g2in1v7bhclv/e41n570nep6dionm41b8g25ennqqspmh/1367863200000/14985545053951403951/14985545053951403951/0B9G3K3KUUcIISUdXMHkycUNFLVE?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: doc-04-9o-docs.googleusercontent.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer ya29.***************************************
> 
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

When I change my authorization bearer request header to something I know is invalid, eg. "foobar" I get a 401 unauthorized response.  However when I query the metadata with my valid key I get back a download url and webcontent url.  I can see the file in the browser when I'm logged in, but downloadUrl fails.
The procedure I'm following is described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

UPDATE:
if I remove the gd=true parameter I get a 302 with a location header to a link that works.  Is the downloadUrl coming back from google incorrect?

UPDATE2:
I am making the request immediately after retrieving the downloadUrl in the metadata, I am aware the documentation specifies it is a short-lived URL.

UPDATE3:
for reference this is a downloadUrl retrieved by the same methods which was able to succesfully retrieve the image:
 https://doc-0s-9o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/kgbtvvv26q246qm8m1k4g2in1v7bhclv/q8d8m0pthrvjbje5srvraoe864okrb5r/1367870400000/14985545053951403951/14985545053951403951/0B9G3K3KUUcIIRWgxLVZpSzBfdWM?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true

Comment: We're investigating...

Comment: Still getting the same 404 error on the majority of files from the downloadUrl.  Disabling Google Drive on our end for now.